# KeyboardAvoidingView & ScrollView (automaticallyAdjustKeyboardInsets) adding big white space between main and bottom container

Tags: react-native

When I tap on the bottom input field, the input field as well as the messages scroll up accordingly so they're still visible and not covered by the keyboard. However, I can scroll up the messages and there is a big space between the last message and the input field, roughly the size of the keyboard.

Although assuming it has to do with using both, KeyboardAvoidingView as well as the prop automaticallyAdjustKeyboardInsets within ScrollView, I wasn't able to nail down the combination of those two in order to push the chat container and the bottom input container up upon keyboard display without any problems.

RN version: 0.70.5
OS: iOS

[Visual explanation of unexpected white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HkC1.gif)

The code:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    ScrollView,
    SafeAreaView,
    TextInput,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    Platform
} from 'react-native';
import Colors from "../utilities/Colors";


const KeyboardTest = ({ navigation }) => {
    const scrollViewRef = useRef();

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>

            {/*Top Bar Container, fixed at the top*/}
            <View style={styles.topBarContainer}>
                <View style={styles.topBarItemContainer}>
                    <Text>This is the top bar container</Text>
                </View>
            </View>

            <KeyboardAvoidingView
                behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
                style={styles.chatContainer}
            >
                <View>
                    <ScrollView
                        horizontal={false}
                        ref={scrollViewRef}
                        onContentSizeChange={() => scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({animated: true})}
                        automaticallyAdjustKeyboardInsets={true}
                    >
                        <View style={styles.chatMessageContainer}>
                            <Text style={styles.message}>This is a message</Text>
                            {/* ... */}
                            <Text style={styles.message}>This is a message</Text>
                        </View>

                    </ScrollView>
                    <View style={styles.bottomBarContainer}>
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.bottomBarTextInput}
                            placeholder={'Type a message'}
                            placeholderTextColor={'#A9A9A9'}
                        />
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                            <View style={styles.bottomBarSendButton}/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>

        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.WHITE,
    },
    topBarItemContainer: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: '100%',
        height: 60,
        backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
    },
    chatContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    },
    chatMessageContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        marginBottom: 60,
    },
    message: {
        fontSize: 25,
        color: 'black',
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin: 15,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
    },
    bottomBarContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: '100%',
        height: 60,
        backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 0,
    },

})

export default KeyboardTest;
```

Expected behaviour:
Top bar container remains fixed
Middle container (chat container) scrollable, scrolls up when keyboard shows
Bottom container (text input field) fixed on bottom, scrolls up when keyboard shows
No unnecessary space between middle and bottom containers

I tried various constellations of KeyboardAvoidingView and ScrollView (with automaticallyAdjustKeyboardInsets).
KAV nested in SV
SV nested in KAV
SV nested in KV nested in SV
Only SV with automaticallyAdjustKeyboardInsets

Every time it was a different issue, eg the bottom container was fully scrollable and not fixed anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure why it didn't work out with the previous approach, but another one works now:

I used FlatList which took care of the problem for me. The structure looks like this now:

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
  <ChatTopBar navigation={navigation} />
  <KeyboardAvoidingView
    behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
    style={styles.keyboardAvoidingContainer}
  >
    <View>
      <View style={styles.chatContainer}>
        <ChatRenderMessages messages={msgs} />
      </View>
      <ChatBottomBar />
    </View>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

The FlatList is within a View in ChatRenderMessages component:

```
<View>
  <FlatList
    inverted
    contentContainerStyle={styles.chatContainer}
    data={messages}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.time}
    renderItem={({ item }) =>
      item.senderID != auth.currentUser.uid ? (
        <View key={item.time} style={styles.chatContainerPartnerMessage}>
          ...
        </View>
      ) : (
        <View key={item.time} style={styles.chatContainerOwnMessage}>
          ...
        </View>
      )
    }
  />
</View>
```

Not sure if that's the best approach, but it works for me. This structure of KeyboardAvoidingView & FlatList does the job.